# Java / from string to java code

Tags: java

I have some value which I get in string format from a file.

For example, in the File A I have:

```
id = 342
name = Jonatan
country = USA
```

In addition, I have class: `person` with the next fields:

```
String id;
String name;
String country;
String grades;
String location;
```

and I have getter and setter for all the fields.

Now, I want to create a new instance of person, which represents Jonatan.
But - I don't want to update all the field, only the fields I need.

So, what I want to do is the next: get the details from the file, and then for every one do set, and update the correct value. For example, `setName(Jonatan)`. The problems is that my `name` is in a String format. so I cant do setName - because name is in a string format, and Java doesn't give me the option of call a method in a string format.

There is easy way to it?

Comment: "*Java doesn't give me the option of call a method in a string format*" - I don't understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a look at [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.basic)

The application is pretty simple - to call setId("42") of a person call:

```
PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(person, "id", "42");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using java reflection you can determine what methods/fields are available.

You can use this example to pass your key/value pairs into the `doReflection` method to set the new values of your properties in the instance of the Bean-class.

```
public class Bean {

    private String id = "abc";

    public void setId(String s) {
        id = s;
    }

    /**
     * Find a method with the given field-name (prepend it with "set") and
     * invoke it with the given new value.
     * 
     * @param b The object to set the new value onto
     * @param field  The name of the field (excluding "set")
     * @param newValue The new value
     */
    public static void doReflection(Bean b, String field, String newValue) throws NoSuchMethodException,
            SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<? extends Bean> c = b.getClass();
        Method id = c.getMethod("set" + field, String.class);
        id.invoke(b, newValue);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException,
            InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        System.out.println("ID before: " + bean.id);
        doReflection(bean, "Id", "newValue");
        System.out.println("ID after: " + bean.id);

        // If you have a map of key/value pairs:
        Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(Entry<String, String> entry : values.entrySet())
            doReflection(bean, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: This should be a comment. At least show an example if you consider this as an answer

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

I like @michael_s's answer with `BeanUtils`. If you want to do it without, you can write:

```
Person person = new Person();
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("the.properties"));
for (Object key : properties.keySet()) {
    String field = (String) key;
    String setter = "set" + field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.substring(1);
    Method method = Person.class.getMethod(setter, String.class);
    method.invoke(person, properties.get(key));
}
```

Not that the stream should be closed after using it, and that this short example only works for `String` properties.